# Node as an API micro-service gateway

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, microservices, traefik

Currently we use Traefik as our API gateway. Although this is obviously lacking in things we will want in the future:

- Authentication
- Caching
- etc...

We are considering a very simple nodejs service acting as a gateway/proxy to our internal services. Will node have the same ***performance*** or similar to Nginx / Traefik for this purpose?

Comment: From what point of view?

Comment: From the perspective of an external user, making requests into our system.

Comment: If you write the right code then yes, it could be transparent what server is responding to the client's requests.

Comment: More referring to a performance perspective.